# How to send a command to an aggregate without knowledge about the identifier?

Tags: java, cqrs, axon

I have a question regarding mapping of a RESTful APIs and aggregates/entities in Axon.

Let’s say we’re in the cinema domain and start with a movie context encapsulated in a microservice. We’ve a Movie entity (aggregate) and a bunch of related commands and events.

```java
@Aggregate
class Movie {

  @AggregateIdentifier
  private MovieId movieId;

  // omitted handlers, getters and setters

}
```

The related URL could look like `/movies/<movieId>`

Now I would like to introduce a new context/microservice for rating of movies. Movie ratings are related to a movie and a movie has no knowledge about their existence. But at the end I would like to address the ratings via the movie represented by it’s id. The URL could look like this `/movies/<movieId>/ratings`

So the entity might look somehow like this:

```java
@Aggregate
class MovieRatings {

  @AggregateIdentifier
  private MovieRatingsId movieRatingsId;

  // the related movie
  private MovieId movieId;

  // a list of movie related ratings
  private List<Rating> movieRatings;

  // omitted handlers, getters and setters
}
```

The question is, does it make sense to create such an aggregate here? If no, how could an cqrs-based-alternative look like? And if yes, how can I address it via a command (e.g. AddRating) fired e.g. in my controller if I only know the movie identifier?

Comment: It makes sense. But keep in mind that aggregate root makes C in CQRS. How you fetch movie ratings makes Q. In other words, you don’t use AR to query data. That’s what read model is used for and it can differ from command model i.e. AR. Taking all that in consideration, there is no need for MovieRatings AR. Rename it to MovieRating and remove Rating list.

Comment: What business decisions is the MovieRatings aggregate going to make based on that list of Rating objects? Without knowing all your requirements, I would probably not use a MovieRatings aggregate, but model the AddRating command as acting on the Movie aggregate, and like @ZeljkoVujaklija said, the list of Ratings probably belongs in a query table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Zeljko Vujaklija and @Mzzl for the hints! I've adjusted the MovieRating aggregate:

```java
@Aggregate
class MovieRating {

  @AggregateIdentifier
  private MovieRatingsId movieRatingsId;

  // the related movie
  private MovieId movieId;

  private Rating rating;

  // omitted handlers, getters and setters
}
```

And just use the movieId to query the movie related ratings. A simple `POST` to `movies/<movieId>/ratings` with the rating in body creates a movie rating and a `GET` retrieves the related data. 
Even editing of ratings using `/movies/<movieId>ratings/<ratingId>` would be possible.